# Defining a variable before or within a loop

Tags: c

Is there a difference between the following two approaches to defining a for-loop variable in C?

```c
int i;
for (i = 0; i < X; i++) {
    // something
}
```

And:

```c
for (int i = 0; i < X; i++) {
    // something
}
```

My preference is to use the second approach if the `i` is just always a throw-away, but is there any reason that it wouldn't be a good idea to do that?

Comment: I'd always go for the second, but in older versions of C, you can't do it.

Comment: @ThomasJager -- is it 'expensive' to re-define the `int` in the loop? Or does it only define it once, at the beginning? Perhaps if you can explain your comment, etc. I'll award the answer.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is broad and opinion-based. See [ask]. Having said that, it's customary to use the second unless you're using ANSI C.

Comment: Any decent compiler should produce the same code regardless of where you declare the variable.

Comment: And if there's a difference, the performance impact will be negligible. The second version is considered more idiomatic, unless you need to use `i` after the loop is done

Comment: @ggorlen -- I wasn't sure if they were the same. Basically, to me being a novice, I would think that the `int i=0` would be repeated X times, so the first one would be better (but obviously from the comments this seems wrong). If not, why would they be "basically the same" I guess is my question.

Comment: If you step through the code for the second example you'll see that `i` is only getting declared and initialized once. If it was getting reinitialized every time, the loop would never exit!

Comment: The second approach is illegal in C89.

Comment: Sometimes you want to declare the `i` outside scope and re-use it to continue iterating from the last element it stopped at in the previous loop.

Comment: The best way to understand this is to look at the assembly code that the compiler generates (`-S` for gcc or clang, or look at the assembly with a debugger). What you find (typically) is that the compiler reserves space for all of the variables at the beginning of the function, regardless of where the variables are declared. Even when variables are declared inside the loop body, the space for the variables is reserved at the top of the function.

Comment: @user3386109 sorry for the silly question, but what's the difference between the `.s` file this does and the `.out` file it does otherwise?

Comment: @Shared the first block of a `for` loop (`for (initialize; condition; post block)`) only runs one time. `for` loops are basically syntactic sugar.

Comment: @Shared The `.s` file is a text file that you can look at. It contains the output of the compiler in human-readable form. The `.out` file is the executable file. It is a binary file containing non-human-readable machine code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but is there any reason that it wouldn't be a good idea to do that?

In C, you should prefer the second form, because it reduces the scope of the variable and makes it more obvious where it is going to be used. Unless...

- ...it goes against the coding guidelines of a given project. For instance, the Linux kernel declares all variables at the top of a function.
- ...you want to be conforming to C90: you cannot use loop initial declarations.

In C++, however, objects may have very expensive constructors, which means that, at times, you may want to re-use them rather than initialize a new one every time (e.g. if you construct a new one within the body of the loop).

Comment: What do object constructors have to do with declaring an integer counter inside or outside a loop? Seems like a totally different scenario unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: @ggorlen OP is asking about variables in general, not only integer counters.

Comment: There's no re-initializing "a new one every time" in either example OP provided though, they're both initialized once. The question is whether to declare out of a loop scope or do both inside the loop scope and makes no mention of C++.

Comment: @ggorlen He wasn't talking about initialization, he was talking about *construction* which, yes, can be expensive.

Comment: @ggorlen By "within a loop" in the title, I understand even in the *body* of the loop, not just in the init clause. I clarified the answer.

Comment: The title says that but the code doesn't. I take "within a loop" to be exactly what the code says, which is "within the initializer block of a `for` construct".

Comment: @ggorlen When there is a mismatch between the text/title and the example/code given, I always favor the text/title, because the examples/code may simply be a particular example, not the whole question. If we went with your interpretation, we may be misleading OP. If we go with the more general one, we don't.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

As the `i` variable is usually used only to count the number of iterations needed, it doesn't make sense to have a variable live outside the scope of the loop. That, if you can, should be avoided.

As some comments to the question mention, there are some cases in which you can't use the second, but that's not the general case.

As for the compiler later compiling to the same assembly, that may be true, but conceptually the second is cleaner, and for someone reading the code from outside, it makes it clear that the variable is never used again.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of differences between the two.

The second form is illegal in the 1989 ANSI (1990 ISO) C standard.   The first is supported in C from 1999 and in standard C++.   It is supported by some C compilers older than 1999, either as a non-standard or optional extension or because those compilers were actually C++ compilers with a C mode.

In the first form, `i` exists after the loop, so its value can still be accessed, but redefining it results in a diagnostic (compile time error).    In the second form, `i` does not exist after the loop, so accessing its value after the loop gives a diagnostic, but `i` can be redefined.

In general terms, it is advisable to ensure that variables only exist for as long as needed, and cease to exist when no longer needed.    The second form explicitly allows that.

Obviously, variables that need to exist outside the loop, need to be defined outside it.    But, if the variable `i` is not needed outside the loop, then I would favour the second form.   This allows the compilers to catch problems, such as unintended use of variable `i` after the loop.

Some older C and C++ compilers (mainly dating from before the 1998 C++ standard was ratified, but some from the early 2000s) implement the second form so the variable `i` still exists after the loop.   This effectively makes the two forms equivalent when using those compilers.